# Delete ManyToMany link

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm newbie in Hibernate and I've a question about it.

I've 3 tables: User, Role and UserRole.

User and Role have ManyToMany relationship mapped by UserRole.

I have 2 rows in Role: (1, ROLE_ADMIN) (2, ROLE_USER).
I have 1 row in User: (1, TESTUSER).
I have 2 rows in UserRole: (1,1)(1,2).

I have 2 Entities: UserEntity and RoleEntity.

I added 2 role to TESTUSER calling method .add( Role ) on UserEntity and after .save( User ) on Session.

I can add all role i want to TESTUSER and it's works!

When i call .remove( Role ) on UserEntity and after .save( User ) on my JPA repository. It doesn't work.

I mean that hibernate doesn't execute any query to delete elements by table UserRole. Why?
Can you help me?

**RoleEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role" , uniqueConstraints= {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={ "role_id" }) ,
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={ "name" }) 
})
@Indexed
public 
        class Role
        implements Serializable
{    

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy="roleList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>(0); 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private
        Long roleId; 

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private
        String name;
```

**UserEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user" , uniqueConstraints= {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={ "user_id" }) ,
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={ "name" }) 
})
@Indexed
public 
        class User
        implements Serializable
{    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<>(0); 

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private
        String name;
```

**My test code:**

```
Role adminRole = new RuoloBuilder().setName("ROLE_ADMIN").build();
Role userRole = new RuoloBuilder().setName("ROLE_USER").build();

adminRole = roleService.saveOrUpdate(adminRole);
userRole = roleService.saveOrUpdate(userRole);

User user = new UtenteBuilder()
     .setName("TESTUSER")
     .setRoleList(Arrays.asList(adminRole, userRole))
     .build();
user =  userService.saveOrUpdate(user); // It works
user.getRoleList().remove(userRole);
userService.saveOrUpdate(user); // It doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL) // on the entity User
```

You have to cascade all the operations `PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH` to the linked entities (Roles).

Comment: Thak you but I solved adding methods equals and hashCode to my entities and now it works fine.